# Can't locate object method "host" via package "URI::foreign" at PERL2EXE_STORAGE/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 157

Tags: json, perl, rest-client

I have an application using Perl and Tk
The version of Perl we are using is v5.30.3
I have written a program for communicating with a REST api sending JSON data.

Here is the program

```
use REST::Client;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

@reference = undef; @authCode = undef; @line = undef; $num = 0;

$merchantId = 1000005;

@posData = undef;

$posData[1] = 'Manual';     #panCaptureMethod
$posData[2] = 'false';      #cardPresent
$posData[3] = 'Attended';       #deviceAttendance
$posData[4] = 'KeyedOnly';      #deviceInputCapability
$posData[5] = 'OnPremise';      #deviceLocation
$posData[6] = 'Supported';      #partialApprovalSupport
$posData[7] = 'Unknown';        #pinCaptureCapability

$index = (index($exp, "/"));
$month = substr($exp,0,$index);
$year  = substr($exp,$index+1);


    my $client = REST::Client->new();
    $client->setHost("https://sandbox.api.mxmerchant.com/checkout/v3/");        
    $client->addHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    $client->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $client->addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic TkxvTXhDdlNzaWpSNFJkOHFPWEx5QV=');           

    $amt = sprintf('%.2f',$amt);
    %rec_hash = (
        merchantId => $merchantId,
        tenderType => "Card",
        amount => $amt,
        paymentType => "Sale",
        cardAccount => {
                number => $card,
                expiryMonth => $month,
                expiryYear => $year,
                cvv => $cvv,
                avsStreet => $GA_A[6],
                avsZip => $zip
        },
        customer => {
                name => $name,
                firstName => $fname,
                lastName => $lname
        },
        posData => {
                cardholderPresence => $cardholderPresence,
                panCaptureMethod => $posData[1],
                cardPresent => $posData[2],
                deviceAttendance => $posData[3],
                deviceInputCapability => $posData[4],
                deviceLocation => $posData[5],
                partialApprovalSupport => $posData[6],
                pinCaptureCapability => $posData[7]
        }
    );


    my $json = encode_json \%rec_hash;

    $client->POST('payment?echo=true', $json);
    $response = $client->responseContent();
    $json_data = decode_json($response);

    $error = 'NO';
    $status = $json_data->{status};
    $authMessage = $json_data->{authMessage};
    $errorCode = $json_data->{errorCode};
    $errorMessage = $json_data->{message};

    $message = $authMessage;
    if ($errorCode ne '')
    {
        $error = 'YES';
        $status = $errorCode;
        $message = $errorMessage;
    }

    $reference = $json_data->{reference};
    $authCode = $json_data->{authCode};

return($status, $message, $error);
```

When I run this program using perl.exe with all of the necessary path statements in the environment variables it works. It sends the request and I get the proper response.

The problem I'm having is that when I use our compiled .exe in a testing environment it doesn't work. The host isn't receiving any kind of request and the data that is in the $response is

'Can't locate object method "host" via package "URI::foreign" at PERL2EXE_STORAGE/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 157'

To create the compiled exe I am using Indigo Star Perl2exe

I've tried adding packages, updating packages.

Comment: First rule of perl: `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.

Comment: Probably missing one of the URI:: modules

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need to bundle `LWP::Protocol::https` in your compiled `.exe`. I suspect this because it appears from the error message you exhibit that your https: URL got parsed as an LWP::Protocol::foreign. LWP::Protocol::https can be tricky because its dependencies ultimately require an external SSL library.

Comment: I’ve switched to PAR Packer and I’ve been able to get much further. My application works mostly. Where I’m having trouble is when I try to run the above program. The program works and there are no errors. If I run it without a compiled exe using just path statements it works and I get a 200 response. When I run it with a compiled exe and I even change the name of my Perl folder I get a 500 response and loaded into the response $Var1 is a message can’t find “new” in LWP::Protocol::https::Socket. This package doesn’t exist and like I said there are no compile errors.

Comment: LWP::Protocol::https::Socket turns out not to be a separate module but a package defined in LWP/Protocol/https.pm. All it contains is `use base qw(Net::HTTPS LWP::Protocol::http::SocketMethods);`. You would need to ensure that these are available in your .exe, figure out which one is supposed to supply the new() method, and go from there based on your findings.